# Error in Exercises from Charles Pinter Abstract Algebra 3.A.3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Exercise 3.A.3, he asks if $\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x \ne -1\}$ with $x*y=x+y+xy$, is an Abelian group, and it follows all needs except that $x*y$ isn't an operation. Since $x\ne-1$, but you can find $y$ such that $x*y=-1$ ($y = \frac{-1-x}{1+x}$), it isn't an operation. Is this correct?

Comment: Did you notice that $\frac{-1-x}{1+x} = -\frac{1+x}{1+x} = -1$?

Answer (score 3):

This *is* an operation. Your value for $y$ is
$$y = \frac{-1-x}{1+x} = \frac{-(1+x)}{1+x} = -1,$$
which is not in your set. So in fact, $y$ cannot take that value.